# How can I authenticate a mobile user is logged into their FB account when they make requests to my apps server side API?

Tags: android, facebook

My app uses api calls from the mobile app to a server backend. I've implemented facebook login to the app and can login there, but I want to know how my server side can verify that the user is logged in to the account it claims.

I could simply use facebook login as a sign up tool and create a password for my app on first login, but I'd prefer all the authentication was done with the facebook login itself.

Comment: use accessToken and userID

Comment: @brykneval Are access tokens static or dynamic? When and how do they change, what would the server need to do to know what the current one is?

Answer (score 0):

Once user validates via Facebook or any Oauth,
you have accessToken (with details of information that one can access) and userId (determining the user) provided by host (i.e. Facebook) and you should store that on server. So on startup you can check if accesstoken is null or not and if its not null go to next page of app.

For profile and accessToken

```
String profile = com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId()
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
```

No userId doesnt change however accesstoken as is dependent on what you have right to access at that moment may change if you need more information.

Comment: I assume when and if the access token changes, i then make a request to the server with the new and old token, to update the value?

Comment: @SamC no you shouldn't most probably for simple authentication, its needed when you need info like name, age . . . from facebook which is totally independent to your system's authorization

Comment: But if the access token changes, my server will still have the old one and deny any requests made with the new one?

Comment: @SamC generally you dont fetch information everytime from facebook, but if you want to you can using AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(); which gives you current accesstoken.

Comment: Will the currentAccessToken ever change? Is the same token issued if the user logs on from another device?

Comment: @SamC yes if you decide you want more information from user than previous one you had

Comment: What happens if a new access token is given. Is the old one kept anywhere? How would I update it server side.